# Merged list items with CSS border-radius if they are next to each other?

Tags: css, vue.js

I am creating a web app (a side project!), I try to make it look good and came across a little CSS challenge , can you help me?

## Examples because it's easier with pictures:

### Example 1

What I get :

[image]

What I want :

[image]

### Example 2

What I get :

[image]

What I want :

[image]

I hosted a very simple vuejs example here : https://jsfiddle.net/ep8ny04d/3/

```
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  &.active {
    background: #39a374;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

*(My screenshots come from this example.)*

So the problem is: Two elements have to be sticked together, but the border-radius of elements have to be changed (or removed for elements in the middle) if two or more elements are selected and next to each other.

**Do you think it's possible to do without Javascript?**

Comment: you could increase bottom padding and set a negative bottom margin of the same amount so they overlap enough to fill the rounded part  https://jsfiddle.net/1hm9x6do/

Comment: @G-Cyr: That breaks once you start toggling items...

Comment: @BoltClock it was a comment about the idea , sibblings and position need to be thought about, i agree ;) debugged idea https://jsfiddle.net/1hm9x6do/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get most of the way there using a combination of sibling combinators, `:first-child`, `:last-child`, and `:not()` (note that you need to remove the `border-radius: 10px` declaration from the top-level `li` rule):

```css
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  &.active {
    background: #39a374;
    color: white;
  }
  &.active:first-child, &:not(.active) + .active {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  }
  &.active:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  }
}
```

But that doesn't produce bottom rounded corners for `.active` items appearing immediately before `:not(.active)` items. You'd need to add another class to those specific items before you can target them with CSS. This can be done within the class binding so you avoid polluting the data model (or indeed, writing additional application logic, which I assume is what you mean by "without JavaScript"...):

```html
<li v-for="(todo,i) in todos"
  v-on:click="toggle(todo)"
  v-bind:class="{active: todo.active, beforeInactive: todo.active && todos[i+1] && !todos[i+1].active}">
  {{i}} Hey
</li>
```

Then referenced within the CSS:

```css
li
  // ...
  &.active:first-child, &:not(.active) + .active {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  }
  // Added reference to new .beforeInactive class
  &.active:last-child, &.beforeInactive {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  }
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/nthjk6c7)

Answer (score 2):

As commented, you may play with padding and margin selecting the position first, or last or next siblings:

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #68d9a7;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li.active {
  background: #39a374;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}
li.active + :not(.active) {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
li:not(.active) + .active {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
li:last-of-type {
  margin: 0;
}
li:first-of-type.active {
    padding:10px;
    
  }
h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
ol {list-style-type:none;padding:0}
```

```html
<div id="app"><h2>Todos:</h2> <ol><li class="active">
      0 Hey
    </li><li class="">
      1 Hey
    </li><li class="active">
      2 Hey
    </li><li class=" ">
      3 Hey
    </li><li class="active">
      4 Hey
    </li><li class="">
      5 Hey
    </li><li class="active">
      6 Hey
    </li><li class="active">
      7 Hey
    </li></ol></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1hm9x6do/2/

SCSS for li

```
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  &.active {
    background: #39a374;
    color: white;
  padding-top:30px;
  margin-bottom:-20px;
  }
  &.active + :not(.active) {
   margin-top:20px;
  }
  &:not(.active) + .active {
    padding-top:10px;
  }
  &:last-of-type{
    margin:0;
    }

  &:first-of-type.active {
    padding:10px;

  }
}
```

Comment: That's more like it. I suppose then it's up to the asker to decide between modifying their template slightly, and sticking to CSS as much as humanly possible...

Comment: I'm referring to my answer. As in, the asker can choose to do it my way or yours.

Comment: @G-Cyr I like your solution too! The problem: I guess it could be fixed somehow, but the clickable zone is altered, making some click unselect the next item in the list. Thank you both for your help, I hope some other people will use these snippets :D